# Объединение двух таблиц по общему столбцу в MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Имеется две таблицы, столбцы первой: `Уникальный_номер, Атрибут1`, столбцы второй: `Уникальный_номер, Атрибут2`. В таблицах разное число строк, некоторые значения столбцов `Уникальный_номер` совпадают, но не все. Необходимо создать запрос `SELECT`, который выдаст таблицу следующего вида: `Уникальный_номер, Атрибут1, Атрибут2`, в которую войдут как полные строки, так и строки с номером, имеющимся хотя бы в одной таблице. В таком случае, для отсутствующего атрибута нужно проставить `0`.

Помогите, пожалуйста, сформировать соответствующий запрос с использованием MS SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(a.Уникальный_номер,b.Уникальный_номер,0), Атрибут1, Атрибут2
FROM table1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 b
ON a.Уникальный_номер=b.t.Уникальный_номер
```

думаю поможет

Answer (score 0):

Вместо отсутствующего атрибута ставим `0`, задаем имена колонкам и используем укороченную версию `FULL JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT 
    ISNULL(t1.Number, t2.Number) AS Number, 
    ISNULL(t1.Attribute1, 0) AS Attribute1, 
    ISNULL(t2.Attribute2, 0) AS Attribute2
FROM table1 t1
FULL JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.Number = t2.Number
```